# Migrate Webstorm Code Highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, javascript

I am currently using Webstorm as my daily driver but I am trying to look into Emacs and possibly transition.

One of the most important things to me that I have spent the last 3 years on was to configure the code highlighting (especially JS and TS) to my liking.

I do not like the default whatsoever in either emacs or Webstrom.

Is there an (easy) way to transform any configurations that I have made in Webstorm to Emacs?

Comment: It should be possible to write a converter to handle these. I don't know whether exported themes are any different to installable ones, but it seems they're in XML format (Emacs has a parser for it built in). It shouldn't be complex to pull off, the most involved part would be figguring out the mapping of their names to Emacs' faces. As of now I don't have time to add one more hobby project to my schedule, but I'd be willing to help out anyone interested in writing such a converter, as I've written one for vim themes before.

Comment: Also, there might be some differences, for instance Emacs doesn't normally font lock numeric literals, and there are extensions for it, so getting a 100% match might be more involved than just writing a theme.

Comment: It's a pity that no one has had the same issue as me. I guess for the time being I will stick to whatever emacs offers and I'll take a look into customising the theme step by step. As I mentioned I am really new to this so that might take some time :)

Comment: I played around a little bit with phpstorm at work today, and I exported a customized theme in both formats (one of which is the .jar file with XML document describing the theme inside, and other format which I haven't looked into yet). I'll see how things are there. I hope I won't end up staying up all night just to write such a converter like I did the last time, as these projects are quite fun.

Comment: If you do, let me know ;)

Comment: `.icls` files only contain the difference from a theme, so they're not suitable. It seems the same applies to `.jar` exports. The format is still XML in both cases, but converting themes will require both the base and the customized theme.